# automating R script using Mac's Automator and Calendar

Tags: r, macos, automation, icalendar

I have been trying to run a script automatically using the [steps that I found online](http://pleasepasstheroc.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-source-r-script-automatically-on.html).

I am trying to run the following R script called `AUTO.R`

Here is what the script contains:

```
library(quantmod)
obs <- last(Ad(getSymbols("SPY", auto.assign=FALSE)))
saveRDS(obs, "SAMPLE.rds")
```

When I build the application it prints `Workflow completed`

[image: AUTOMATOR]

I believe all is well until the time comes to run the script. The alarm pop-up in my desktop is displayed from Calendar but nothing runs. After a few minutes the folder where the `.rds` file should be saved does not contain anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggested changes:

- Your Automator task should be more like just `/usr/local/bin/Rscript --vanilla /Users/rimeallthetime/Desktop/AUTO.R`
- You should explicitly set the path in `saveRDS`; i.e. `saveRDS(obs, "/Users/rimeallthetime/Desktop/SAMPLE.rds")`

Honestly, though, you should at least make a `~/bin` dir (i.e. a directory called `bin` under your home directory, so in your case `/Users/rimeallthetime/bin` and put both the workflow and R script in there, and I'd also suggest creating another directory for output files vs the desktop.

UPDATE

I just let the calendar event run and this is really a crude way to automate what you want to do. You'd be better off in the long run [using `launchd`](https://superuser.com/questions/373813/how-do-i-run-an-automator-action-shell-script-or-applescript-on-startup-in-os-x), that way it's fully automated and requires no human intervnention at all (but you may need to adjust your script to send you a notification or "append" to the `rds` file).

Comment: thanks for responding, when i try to run the Automator task with the provided code i get the following error: `Run Shell Script failed - 1 error : file name is missing`